# curl to get attachment and change its contents

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to get a m3u file with curl. The file comes as an attachment to the server response like this: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.m3u"`.

With curl in my php page I need to get that m3u file, change its contents and return back the changed content as a new m3u file.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//add these to make your php file a downloadable m3u. 
//Without this VLC won't know how to process it.
//header('Content-Type: audio/x-mpegurl');
//header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 


function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream");


    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);  



    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


    return $data;
}


$url = 'myurltogetfile';

$fileContent = file_get_contents_curl($url);

echo $fileContent;
?>
```

Any ideas?

thank you!

Comment: curl will download from url no matter `Content-Disposition` is exist or not, show your code and exact problem

Comment: without knowing input, code and expected output we cant help

Comment: ok, I updated the question! thank you.

Comment: Voting to close this. You provided no information about how you "return back the changed content" - if you had provided a pure HTML example of how to upload the file we might be able to help you - as long as it does not rely on session based authorization / authentication.

Comment: I will return back the changed content with the commented headers. Im not able to get the attached file from curl, so I cant do the follwoing: change the content and then return it as a file. If I return a file wiht those headers it will be a 0kb file.